# Using mkdir and ffmpeg in a batch script on recursive folders

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I have many folders with .mp4 files. I wrote a script that takes the mp4 files and converts them into 1 jpeg image per frame. Critically, the output of this script (retained file name, with _frame number appended to the end) goes into a newly created folder with the file basename:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.mp4; do mkdir -p "${f%.*}" && ffmpeg -i ${f} -start_number 000 "${f%.*}/${f}_%03d.jpg"; done
```

I can run this for every parent folder one at a time no problem but I would like to just run it once and get it to run recursively.

I changed the code to:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.mp4/; do mkdir -p "${f%.*}" && ffmpeg -i ${f} -start_number 000 "${f%.*}/${f}_%03d.jpg"; done
```

and tried playing with the mkdir part (by adding ./) but no matter what I do, I get the following error.

**mkdir: cannot create directory ‘*’: Invalid argument**

Is there anything I need to do to allow mkdir to create the appropriate new folders in their respective subfolders?

The file structure is as follows:

```
parent folder
    └── videos_1
        ├── videos_1_basename_1.mp4
        └── videos_2_basename_2.mp4
    └── videos_2
        ├── videos_2_basename_1.mp4
        └── videos_2_basename_2.mp4
.sh script
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `globstar` bash option to recurse in sub-directories and also the `nullglob` option such that the pattern expands as null instead of itself (the reason for your error as explained in another answer):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s globstar nullglob
for f in **/*.mp4; do
  d=${f%.mp4}
  b=$(basename -s.mp4 "$f")
  if mkdir -p "$d"; then
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -start_number 000 "$d/${b}_%03d.jpg"
  else
    printf 'could not mkdir %s\n' "$d"
  fi
done
```

Note: for a video named:

```
videos_1/videos_1_basename_1.mp4
```

this will create JPEG files named:

```
videos_1/videos_1_basename_1/videos_1_basename_1_000.jpg
videos_1/videos_1_basename_1/videos_1_basename_1_001.jpg
...
```

If you really want to keep the `.mp4` extension in the names:

```
videos_1/videos_1_basename_1/videos_1_basename_1.mp4_000.jpg
...
```

just remove the `-s.mp4` option of `basename`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried and got the error - Could not open file : videos_1/videos_1_basename/videos_1_basename.mp4_000.jpg
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Input/output error. Do you have any ideas what might cause this?

Comment: Was the sub-directory properly created?

Comment: Yes it was indeed

Comment: Strange. Did you test the `ffmpeg` command manually? Are you under Windows and does it expect backslashes instead of slashes in paths?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 20.04. I tested the following command manually (within the folder) and it worked perfectly. for f in *.mp4; do mkdir -p "${f%.*}" && ffmpeg -i ${f} -start_number 000 "${f%.*}/${f}_%03d.jpg"; done - I just double checked to see if it  was written correctly in my question, and seems to be

Comment: Could it be that `ffmpeg` must be run in the directory in which you want to create the JPEG files? What if you run the command from the top-level directory: `ffmpeg -i videos_1/videos_1_basename/videos_1_basename.mp4 -start_number 000 "videos_1/videos_1_basename/videos_1_basename_%03d.jpg"`?

Comment: My bad! I just realized that I restarted from your own command that cannot work as is: `$f` in the destination file name was the full path while it should be the basename. I fixed my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243153/discussion-between-cebola-and-renaud-pacalet).

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting to use `find` command to get all `*.mp4` under current directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
for currFile in $(find -name "*.mp4"); do
  currDir="${currFile %.mp4}"
  mkdir -p "$currDir"
  ffmpeg -i "$currFile " -start_number 000 "$currDir/${currFile}_%03d.jpg"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

`*.mp4/` would, due to the appended `/`, expand to all **directories** where the name ends in `.mp4`. If you don't have directories with such a name, you don't get any wildcard expansion. `f` is therefore set to the string `*.mp4/` and `${f%.*}` yields a lone `*`, as you can try by yourself on the command line. It seems that `mkdir` refuses the creation of directory with such a weird name; I would consider this a feature instead of a bug.

There is no recursion in your code with respect to the directories. You could do a

```
for f in videos_*/*.m4a
```

inside your parent folder. Of course `f` will then also contain the name of the respective subdirectory (for instance `videos_1/videos_1_basename_1.m4a`), and you have to adapt your script to this fact.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I added this and got the exact same error as the answer from Renaud. I'm confused because there is no such error if I have the .sh file and run it within each folder individually. Do you have any ideas for what causes that error?